# Will the accidental of a mordent affect another mordent that is in the same measure?

Tags: theory, sheet-music, accidentals, mordent

[image: mordent with and without sharp in the same measure]

The first mordent in this measure will be played as D , C# , D. The second mordent in the same measure doesn't have a sharp like the first mordent.

Will the sharp accidental of the first mordent affect the second mordent since they are both in the same measure?

There is a very similar question ([Would an accidental in a mordant still be effective for the whole measure?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/86043/70803)); however, the question itself is not specific to this situation, and although the primary answer addresses it, it's ambiguous.

I'm looking for a documented answer to this specific case.

Comment: It is a hypothetical question, or are you asking about some specific piece?

Comment: Related question, but when the ornament is explicitly notated: [Do accidentals on ornaments apply to the same notes elsewhere in the measure?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/5716/70803).

Comment: The 1st is a lower mordent with inflected note. The sign you wrote is for a simple mordent. Bothe different anyway!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This scenario is undefined and therefore ambiguous. It should be considered an editorial error.

From Elaine Gould's *Behind Bars*:

> **Accidentals affecting ornaments**
>
> An altered pitch should be confirmed or cancelled for an ornament later in the bar....
>
> An accidental indicated for an ornament should be confirmed or cancelled when the pitch is reiterated later in the bar as a measured note. (p. 84)

Thus, the example given in the question should be written either as

[image: Mordents on D, both with sharps]

and both played D-C#-D, or

[image: Mordents on D, one with sharp, one with natural]

with the first played D-C#-D and the second played D-Cnatural-D.

In the ambiguous situation, the only recourse would be:

1. look to original sources;
2. look to recorded evidence;
3. make a decision based on musical analysis.

Comment: Your answer makes more sense than that other guy's answer. Your answer is how I thought things should be because I thought that the accidental for an ornament (the type of ornament that is not written on the stave) only applies to that ornament that it is attached to. That other guy's answer confused me.